# Python - Reading chunks and break if there is no lines

Tags: python

This piece of code is reading a large file line by line, process each line then end the process whenever there is no new entry:

```
file = open(logFile.txt', 'r')
count = 0

     while 1:
         where = file.tell()
         line = file.readline()
         if not line:
             count = count + 1
             if count >= 10:
               break
             time.sleep(1)
             file.seek(where)
         else:
            #process line
```

In my experence, reading line by line takes very long time, so I tried to improve this code to read chunk of lines each time:

```
from itertools import islice
N = 100000
with open('logFile.txt', 'r') as file:
    while True:
       where = file.tell()
       next_n_lines = list(islice(file, N)).__iter__()
       if not next_n_lines:
          count = count + 1
          if count >= 10:
             break
          time.sleep(1)
          file.seek(where)
       for line in next_n_lines:
        # process next_n_lines
```

This works fine except for the ending part, it doen't end the process (break the while loop) even if there is no more lines in file. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure, but I think iterators always evaluate to `True`, so `if not next_n_lines:` is useless. Edit: `bool(iter([]))` returns `True`, so that indeed seems to be the problem here.

Comment: @Rawing strainge! so do you have any idea how can o fix it?

Comment: If you only have one `for line in next_n_lines` loop, you can simply omit the `.__iter__()` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code already reads large chunks of the file at a time, it just returns one line of the data at a time. You've just added a redundant generator that takes 10 lines at a time, using the read line functionality of the file object.

With only a few exceptions, the best way to iterate over the lines in a file is as follows.

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

If you need to iterate over preset numbers of lines at time then try the following:

```
from itertools import islice, chain

def to_chunks(iterable, chunksize):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        first = next(it)
        # Above raises StopIteration if no items left, causing generator
        # to exit gracefully.
        rest = islice(it, chunksize-1)
        yield chain((first,), rest)


with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for chunk in to_chunks(f, 10):
        for line in chunk:
            ...
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean. Do you suggest that I add the for loop within the while loop? because I need to use the seek function to keep the file opened waitng for new data

Comment: also, for loop with `line = file.readline()` gives me the error:  `ERROR: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`