# Python - Ending for loop if there is no new entry

Tags: python

Following this post: [Python - Reading chunks and break if there is no lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074503/python-reading-chunks-and-break-if-there-is-no-lines)

I've been told that this piece of code is already reading chunk of lines at a time:

```
file = open('logFile.txt', 'r')
count = 0  
while 1:
   where = file.tell()
   for line in file:       
       if not line:
           count = count + 1
           if count >= 10:
               break
           time.sleep(1)
           file.seek(where)
       else:
           try:
               #process line
```

If so, then how can the script check if there is no new lines for some time, end the for loop and continue the script? I treid counting for some time but that doesn't work

Comment: You should look at the answer to that question.

Comment: I don't think you need to do that, as the article you refered, `open()` already help you to figure that out already

Comment: Anything wrong with moving the body of the `if not line:` statement out of the `for line in file` loop?

Comment: @PaulLo the loop keeps waiting for a new line. I wanted to end it if there is no new lines few minutes

Comment: @Rawing How I'm going to check if there is new line or not? I'll have to write `line = file.readline()` and as i understood, this makes the script read line by line instead of chunks. am i right?

Comment: @Learner: The `for line in file` loop will stop when there are no more lines.

Comment: @Rawing i see. but what about the while loop? I use it with seek function to watch the file as a pointer.

Comment: @Learner file is already a "pointer" (actually it's a generator, but they're similar enough). Keeping track of where it stopped is superfluous. It keeps track of that on its own.